# Android : App Wants To Check Internet Connection When Start Up But It Crash

Tags: android, xml-parsing, connection

In My Application I load Data's From Xml and it Sucessfully Loaded But When i Close My Internet Connection It Simply Says Appname Crash..

I check in Stackoverflow all are Sugessting to use `ConnectivityManager` but even my App was crash I don't know Why it Happen plz give ideas and Sugesstion to get over from it

what i need is When my app Starts it want to Check Internet Connection if available my listview will display Else it says Connect to Internet and Try Again

Here is My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL1 = "http://my_server.com/tamil";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    //Context context;
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        isNetworkAvailable(this);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetData().execute();


    }
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    Log.w("INTERNET:",String.valueOf(i));
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        Log.w("INTERNET:", "connected!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String xml;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                url = new URL(URL1);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isw);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                br.close();

                xml = sb.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return xml;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is);


                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    Log.e("TAg1", getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    //Log.e("TAg2", getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_LINK, getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                    menuItems.add(map);
                }


            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());

            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{KEY_TITLE, KEY_LINK}, new int[]{
                    R.id.name});
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                }
            });

        }

        public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
            Node child;
            if (elem != null) {
                if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                    for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
                        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                            return child.getNodeValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }


    }
```

Logcat:

```
c/ussrs/a/studio1.3/config/options/ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
            at com.example.a.ro.MainActivity$GetData.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:132)
            at com.example.a.ro.MainActivity$GetData.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:86)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line number `MainActivity.java:132` ?

Comment: `is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));` @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK he will get xml variable null, because it is not initialized

Comment: @RaviRupareliya: Initializing by `xml = sb.toString(); in `doInBackground`

Comment: yes but what if internet is not available, it will move to catch block right? @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: yes if internet is not available the app wants to say plz Connect to internet @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: @vasanth look at my answer, it will solve your problem

Comment: @RaviRupareliya yup my app was Not Crash But I want to display Error Msg like" Connect to Internet" if network is not available

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Yup Working Perfect Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because when you close your internet connection it will raise exception so it will move to the catch block and finally it returns `xml` variable, which is null
That  is the reason you are getting null pointer exception.

use internet connection condition:

```
if(isNetworkAvailable(this))
    new GetData().execute();
else
    //no internet connection, show your message here
```

Comment: thanks But i want to set Error Msg On startup when network is Not Connected "Connect to Internet" @RaviRupareliya

Comment: yes check my code, in else condition you can show your message

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your AppManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Use this method to check connection

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
return isConnected;
}
```

and set

```
String xml;
```

to

```
String xml = "error";
```

and

```
new GetData().execute();
```

to

```
if(isNetworkAvailable())
new GetData().execute();
```